# How to do probit feature engineering from numerical data (cdf and pdf style) on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-extraction

This question is based on my current understanding (edit for more exact statistical terminology is very Wellcome). In my assumption, probit is the right terminology. I want to do `probit_pdf` and `probit_cdf`

`probit_pdf` is the probability of the variable is equal certain value
 `probit_cdf` is the probability of the variable less or same with value

Here's my data

```
   Id  Value  
    1   2    
    2   4    
    3   2       
    4   6     
    5   5      
    6   4      
    7   2    
    8   4     
    9   2
    10  5
```

To make the question clearer, I give example for few `Id`'s

`probit_pdf` sample, for `Id = 1` :
Here's the expected output, because probability of `Value = 2` is `0.40` (`4`in `10`), so the `probit_pdf` is `0.40`.

`probit_cdf` sample, for `Id = 5`:
And because probability of `Value >= 5` is `0.90` (`9`in `10`), so the `probit_cdf` is `0.90`

So my expected output is

```
Id  Value  probit_pdf   probit_cdf
1   2           0.40         0.40
2   4           0.30         0.70
3   2           0.40         0.40    
4   6           0.10         1.00
5   5           0.20         0.90
6   4           0.30         0.70
7   2           0.40         0.40
8   4           0.30         0.70
9   2           0.40         0.40
10  5           0.20         0.90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for `probit_pdf` use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `size` and divide by length of `DataFrame`, for `probit_cdf` compare each value by all values, get `sum`s and divide same way:

```
lens = len(df)
df['probit_pdf'] = df.groupby('Value')['Value'].transform('size').div(lens)
df['probit_cdf'] = df['probit_pdf'].apply(lambda x: df['probit_pdf'].ge(x).sum()).div(lens)
print (df)
   Id  Value  probit_pdf  probit_cdf
0   1      2         0.4         0.4
1   2      4         0.3         0.7
2   3      2         0.4         0.4
3   4      6         0.1         1.0
4   5      5         0.2         0.9
5   6      4         0.3         0.7
6   7      2         0.4         0.4
7   8      4         0.3         0.7
8   9      2         0.4         0.4
9  10      5         0.2         0.9
```